# How would I make these slices within an aggregate group by more programmatic?

Tags: python, pandas, function

I had to set up 3 different functions for the slices I wanted to incorporate alongside the count, mean, median aggregate calls. Is there an easier way?

```py
def from_0_up_to_6(x):
    return (x < 6).sum()
def from_6_up_to_12(y):
    return ((y >= 6) & (y < 12)).sum()
def from_12_and_up(z):
    return (z >= 12).sum()

MonthsUntilBUGift = df.groupby('BusinessUnit').agg({'MonthsTillBUGift': ['mean','count','median'
                                                                        , from_0_up_to_6
                                                                        , from_6_up_to_12
                                                                        , from_12_and_up
                                                                        ]})
```

Desired results are fine, but my concern is when stakeholders choose to redefine the ranges/slices, which could make me go crazy.

Comment: Some sample data and more specific requirements would be helpful here! Review [ask] and [mcve] while you're at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import partial

bounds = [0, 6, 12, float('inf')]


def agg(lower, upper, x):
    return ((lower <= x) & (x < upper)).sum()


aggs = [
    partial(agg, lower, upper)
    for lower, upper in zip(bounds, bounds[1:])
]

print(aggs)
# [functools.partial(<function agg at 0x10afad7b8>, 0, 6), functools.partial(<function agg at 0x10afad7b8>, 6, 12), functools.partial(<function agg at 0x10afad7b8>, 12, inf)]
```